# How to access mysql database from the <item> selected in drop down spinner

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, xamarin.android, database-connection

I have a dropdown spinner as shown below.

[image]

and a data similar to this in 000webhost as a SQL database.
[image: database]

Now how can I access the list of collages which offer bachelor's courses when I select "Bachelors Degree" from "Course" dropdown spinner.

How can I access this entire database from 000webhost to my application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to "expose" your MySQL data to C# with a (webbased) API, trust me you don't want to allow the C# apps to directly connect to MySQL..

Comment: C# apps can be disassembled with ease, meaning your MySQL user/password is on the street for anyone that knows how to do that..

Comment: Then you might think o i will use a C# obfuscator to protect the code, well that makes it bit more harder not impossible..

Comment: Do it loke all other app developer. Set up a webserver with oho and access the data via php script. and return for example json.